# Android Studio auto suggestion code popup text color

Tags: android-studio

How I can change the suggestions' text color in the code completion popup?

It is hard to read when using the Darcula scheme.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To change the color of the code suggestions popup you need to do the following:

1. Go to File -> Settings
2. Editor -> General -> Code Completion
3. Check the box where it says **"Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc."**

[image]

Comment: Hmmmmm... and where is the change text color option?

Comment: @Esperanz0 - Go to the same place, but under Color Scheme -> General you will find all the different configurations you can change to adjust color.

Comment: But without this Check box in Code Completion configurations in Color Scheme -> General are also available... question is which one is for text presented on screen in first question

Comment: @Esperanz0 - Please try the suggested solution and see that it works. I have tried it in my Android Studio. If it works for you, mark my answer as the answer.

Comment: I will mark as answer if there will be screen with color text changed and how  to adjust color.